# Change logo on a specific page class

Tags: jquery, joomla

I work with Joomla and I want to change the logo image source on a specific body class.

So when I have

```
<body class="itemid-131">
```

the src here:

```
<img class="sp-default-logo" src="images/logo.png">
```

to be:

```
<img class="sp-default-logo" src="images/logo-white.png">
```

Thank you

Comment: `$('body.itemid-131 img.sp-default-logo').attr('src', 'images/...')`

Comment: You can do $('.sp-default-logo').attr('src', 'images/logo-white.png')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this (i replaced the body with a div just for the example) :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.itemid-131 .sp-default-logo').attr('src', 'images/logo-white.png');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemid-131">
  <img class="sp-default-logo" src="images/logo.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you. An easy way to change the src of another class to have the same result? I mean except the "sp-default-logo" to add another one class.

Comment: @geoplous You can do the same. As you can see i use a selector inside the `$( )` to select the needed element then i use the function `attr` to change an attribute and in this case it's the src. So you may change the selector as per your needs